# Converting date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking to convert the following date

```
select (CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEADD(year, + 1,CONVERT(varchar(11), getdate(),111)))),datename(month,getdate()) for it returns 'jun 26 2015' ,'JUne'
```

I needed it to return as the following '2015/6' , June

This gives me what I want when using just get date

```
select CONVERT(varchar(7), getdate(), 111) = 2014/06
```

but I need it +1 year on my timewait field.

My actual code is as follows:

```
SELECT  c.account_owner_by_SalesDiv, CONVERT(varchar(7), a.timeWait, 111)as rollingdate, DATENAME(MOnth, a.timeWait)
FROM            SalesForce.dbo.SalesForceContact AS b INNER JOIN
                     Dossier_Replication.dbo.vw_SFAD_Contact_data AS c ON b.ContactID = c.CONTACTID__C RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     satVRS.dbo.rptNECACallHistory AS a ON b.UserID = a.UserID_Caller
WHERE        (b.Platform = 'HandsonVRS') AND (a.timeWait BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(year, - 1, CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, 
                     GETDATE()-1), 0), 120)), 120) AND CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0), 101)) AND (a.isReport = '1') AND (a.NECA_isReport = '1') AND
                      (a.ConvoTime > '0') AND (c.account_owner_by_SalesDiv IN ('Enterprise Account', 'National Account', 'Major Account', 'House Account', 'Inside Sales Account'))
GROUP BY c.account_owner_by_SalesDiv, CONVERT(varchar(7), a.timeWait, 111), DATENAME(MOnth, a.timeWait)
order by rollingdate
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think something like this would work: but I get failed to covert string date.    select (convert(varchar(7),(DATEADD(year, + 1,CONVERT(varchar(7), getdate(), 111)))))

Answer (score 0):

This gives `2015/06, June`:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(YEAR,1,GETDATE()), 111) + ', ' + DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())
```

If you don't want the leading zero you could use the SUBSTRING function to trim it.